# Unable to delete workflows

Tags: workflow

I was testing using workflows to process items in a list, but decided that wasn't the best solution. Now I have two workflows attached to the list, and I am trying to delete them.

When I click "delete" in Sharepoint Designer 2013, I get a spinning circle and it just hangs there, not updating.

I also tried deleting the item from the workflow settings in the list online, but once I choose "remove" and click "okay," the page just sits there loading, and eventually times out.

Is there something I am missing in the process of deleting a workflow? One of the workflows even says it has no running instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to PowerShell I would recommend workarounding with that:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell  

#Set the $ErrorActionPreference to "STOP" so that the script stops if there are any errors  

$ErrorActionPreference = "STOP"  

#Declare the Variables 
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sp2010" 

$listToCancel = "CodePlex Links" 

$list = $web.Lists[$listToCancel] 

$tempList = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List``1[System.Object]" 

#Workflow Name.  check against the Workflow Status Column 
$wfToKeep = "Demonstration Workflow" 

foreach ($wf in $list.WorkFlowAssociations) { 

if ($wf.Name -ne $wfToKeep) { $tempList.Add($wf); } 

 } 

foreach ($wf in $tempList){ $list.RemoveWorkflowAssociation($wf); }
```

(Credit to Sudip Misra)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/4a4a8c3e-23cf-4334-bdf4-3db6e838f06d/deleting-sharepoint-2013-designer-workflow-from-powershell?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to Powershell. I have limited access to the server, specifically for my current project. Any other ideas?